# Unable to connect to AWS S3 from CLI with HTTTP/HTTPS proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Someone help me. I've tried every possible way in my capacity to resolve the issue  but couldn't resolve it. I can easily access the AWS-s3 from cli of my local windows machine which is having very flexible proxy setup. But when i'm trying to connect to any AWS service from a remote machine which is basically a virtual windows server, I'm getting proxy Authentication error. The virtual machine is having highly secure proxy of my company but HTTPS, TCP and HTTP ports are open and internet is working properly in the system. I added environment variables for HTTP and HTTPS proxy but it's of no use in my case. The issue persist even after re-configuring and re-installing the aws cli and aws sdk for windows.

[Error Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPEd3.jpg)

[Proxy Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fusqC.jpg)

Comment: are the ports on windows vm open in firewall ?

Comment: you probably have an NTLM proxy which is not supported by the AWS CLI, try [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) as suggested here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-http-proxy.html

Comment: @RikTurnbull, Yes, I just checked. We are using NTLM proxy only. I'll try to configure CNTLM.  Thanks.

Comment: @KushVyas Yes port is open. I'll configure CNTLM. Thanks for your support.